# 404 Not Found1 error on Magento

Tags: magento

I am fresher for Magento. Learning the concepts by implementing the below url.
http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-developper-guide-howto-tutorial-5

I have gone through the first four steps.While implementing on my local,i will get error as

Whoops, our bad...

The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.

```
    If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.
    If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.
```

When i browse this url http://localhost/magento/test/index.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the table `core_config_data` in your database and change the value **http://localhost/magento/test/** by  **http://127.0.0.1/magento/test/**.

Clear cache and check your site.